# Application not found

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, system-error

I have a Sony Xperia P, with Android ICS. I have Ingress installed on my phone. Today, I synced my phone, and Ingress got updated. I had an icon on the homescreen. However - whenever I click on the shortcut, the toast message appears and says `Application Not Found`. I can't find the Ingress icon in applications list too.

I thought that it might get accidentally uninstalled, so I went to Play store to download it again, but I can see that it's already installed on my phone. I clicked on open button and Ingress got opened, and is still working fine.

So what is wrong here? I didn't yet try to reinstall the app, and don't want to do that. Where's the app-icon, and how can I get it back?

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happened on my Nexus - you just have to reboot your device, and the Icon will show up.

Most likely Niantic changed the Launcher activity, so the short cut is no longer pointing to the correct activity, hence the error message.

Rebooting the device/restarting the launcher, and then re-adding the home screen shortcut will fix this.

Comment: Ahh, rebooting the device did the trick, I got the application icon, had to delete the old shortcut though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Seems your application points to the app location which was altered or moved with the update.

To solve this, simply delete the existing shortcut icon (by dragging it on to the bin icon which appears after a long press on the shortcut)

Then create a new shortcut icon for the application through the customizing menu. (which appear after a tap or with the press of menu button whipe you're in your home screen)

You may want to reboot the device beforehand.